# Convergence of series in inclomplete normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

I tried to prove that in non-Banach normed vector space there always exists a series which converges absolutely but which does not converge.

The idea was to consider a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converges and try to construct series with that property, but obvious methods like considering $x_n - x_{n-1}$ didn't work.

So, any hints?

Comment: This should be moved to MathSE... but, anyway: put the sup-of-differences norm on infinitely-long vectors of complex numbers each with only finitely-many  non-zero components.

Comment: I agree that this should be moved to MathSE, the result holds in *every* non Banach normed space as the convergence of Cauchy sequences and of absolutely (for an arbitrary Banach, you should say "normal convergence")

Comment: Your example is right, but the point was to prove that in every non-Banach space there is such series.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read carefully, ... but, depending on the precise choice of terminology, (see @DuchampGérardH.E.'s comment), this might be the definition of "not complete".

Comment: It is very easy to check that for normed vector spaces completeness is equivalent to: absolutely convergent series do converge. An immediate consequence: a quotient of a Banach space over a closed linear subspace is complete too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence that does not converge. If any subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges to $x$, then the original Cauchy sequence converges to $x$ as well. Therefore, no subsequence $\{ x_{n_k} \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges. Choose
$$
           n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \cdots
$$
such that
$$
                 \|x_{n}-x_{m}\| < \frac{1}{2^k},\;\;\; n,m \ge n_k.
$$
Then $\|x_{n_i}-x_{n_j}\| < \frac{1}{2^k}$ for $i,j\ge k$. Therefore, the following cannot converge, even though the sum on the right is absolutely convergent:
\begin{align}
         x_{n_k} &= x_{n_1}+(x_{n_2}-x_{n_1})+(x_{n_3}-x_{n_2})+\cdots+(x_{n_k}-x_{n_{k-1}}) \\ &= x_{n_1} +\sum_{j=1}^{k}(x_{n_{j}}-x_{n_{j-1}}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using the proof of TrialAndError one sees that

*Proposition* In every normed space (NS) the following properties are equivalent

a) the space is Banach

b) every absolutely (for an arbitrary NS, one should say "normally") convergent series is convergent.