# Space where normal convergence does not imply uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence

We know that if we're in a Banach space, normal convergence implies uniform convergence. Is there an easy counterexample outside Banach spaces ?

Comment: Can you please give a precise statement of your first sentence?  What objects are converging?  Are they elements of the Banach space, or functions taking values in the Banach space, or what?  And what exactly do you mean by "normal convergence" in this context?

Comment: For instance, in complex analysis, "normal convergence" usually means "uniform convergence on compact sets", and it certainly does not imply uniform convergence of the functions as a whole.  So you must mean something else, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: @NateEldredge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence

Comment: the maps go from a set X to a vector space E which is not a Banach space.

Comment: Actually I'm kinda realising that it would not mean anything, in the sense that : to converge normally, you need the functions to be bounded. But the set of bounded functions  in this context is a Banach. So it does'nt mean anything to have a normal convergence in a vector space which is not a Banach by definition I guess.
I think I understand where you wanted me to go by asking me those questions

Comment: 1) The space of bounded functions with values in a non-Banach is non-Banach. 2) Please edit your post to clarify it (including something like "the maps go from a set X to a vector space E which is not a Banach space", but better worded if possible).

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968494 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we restrict our attention to *constant* functions, then "normal convergence implies uniform convergence" just becomes the statement that for any sequence $x_n$ in the normed space $X$, if $\sum \|x_n\| < \infty$ then $\sum x_n$ converges in norm.  And this is in fact equivalent to the completeness of $X$, so it is false in *every* incomplete normed space.

The fact that it is true in complete spaces is well known.  Conversely, suppose $X$ is a normed space in which the statement holds.  Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$.  Then for every $k$, there exists some $N_k$ such that for all $m,n \ge N_k$, we have $\|x_m - x_n\| \le 1/2^k$.  Consider the sequence $y_k = x_{N_{k+1}} - x_{N_k}$, so that $\|y_k\| \le 1/2^k$; then $\sum y_k$ converges.  But the $j$th partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^j y_k$  of this series is just $x_{N_j} - x_{N_1}$, so we have shown that the sequence $x_{N_j}$ converges; that is, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence.  Since $x_n$ was already Cauchy, it follows by a standard triangle inequality argument that in fact $x_n$ itself converges.

Comment: This is the proof that Banach <=> (absolute convergence => pointwise convergence)

Comment: Yes.  What I am saying that, as a direct consequence of that fact, $X$ is Banach if and only if normal convergence for sequences of $X$-valued functions implies uniform convergence.

Comment: I misread the first sentence. This is working I guess

Comment: To rephrase, if $X$ is not complete then there exists a sequence of elements $x_n$ such that $\sum \|x_n\| < \infty$ but $\sum x_n$ diverges.  Thus, for any domain $T$ we can take the constant functions $f_n : T \to X$ defined by $f_n(t) = x_n$ for all $t$, and then $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of $X$-valued functions which "converges normally" but does not converge uniformly (nor even pointwise).  Indeed the word "converge" in the definition of "normal convergence" is not really appropriate in this setting.

Comment: This answer is more or less a duplicate of [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1831140).